# Clean design ideas for promoting users to explore more

Tags: website-design, gui-design, style-guide

I have a website which promotes local fitness events. A lot of our site visitors are through Google. They will generally arrive on a specific event page and then leave. I have put suggested events at the end of the current event but most users don't scroll below the page fold to encourage them to explore more events but keen to see if there is a nice way to bring these suggested events higher up in the page fold.

My current idea is to do something similar to add a wikipedia index (but it is quite an ugly option).

Screenshot--------------
[image]
Example page: [https://keepactive.com.au/e/childrens-frenzy-free-8-week-sports-program-2023]

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for desktop.

You have a lot of space on the **right of the page**, use it, put your new content on the right as "cards".

[image: Mock up]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that adding this summary will improve discoverability indeed. Which means users will encounter new content or functionality that they were not aware of previously.

Slack article pages have a better interaction for it though (https://slack.com/help/articles/360017938993-What-is-a-channel)